# Move file to local ANT lib directory?

Tags: file, ant, move

I'm trying to use JarBundler on MacOSX, and on the tutorial I'm using (http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) it says to move the `jarbundler-2.3.1.jar` file to my local ANT lib directory.

I've tried looking up how to do this, but all of the results are for moving files *using* ANT. I don't know how simple it is to do this, but I really cannot find how to do it anywhere on the internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `jarbundler-2.3.1.jar` into the lib directory within your Ant installation directory. I installed Ant at the root of my C: drive, so my Ant lib directory is located at the following location `C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\`. Place the Jar into that folder and your Ant builds will be able to see the task from that Jar anywhere on the system. The Ant lib directory is where the Ant executable looks for Jars containing Ant tasks. Your Ant installation may not be at the root of your C: drive, if you are on Windows it may be in your Program Files directory, or if you are on another OS it may be wherever the default location for installed applications is located. A simple system wide search for "apache-ant" is likely to locate your Ant installation directory (minus quotation marks).

Comment: Okay, didn't realise it was the installation directory. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct but in my humble opinion, modifying the Ant classpath at runtime would be less risky, especially in an open source project, you wouldn't have to explain in your instructions that the developer must put a JAR into the Ant installation directory, the build wouldn't break when you upgrade Ant without doing it again. You can use ant-classloadertask (part of JTools) to do so.

Comment: Why are you going through my comment history disagreeing with me and reviving a "dead" Q/A from 2014? I hope you aren't trying to "pay me back" for disagreeing with you in the other question; I'll assume that you are just trying to be helpful. Regarding your opinion: if you read the question you will see that it asks for specific directions on how and where to place the JAR into the Ant lib directory. Instructions on how to dynamically modify the classpath at runtime don't answer the question that was ask. I agree that JarBundler requiring manual JAR placement is bad, but that is off topic.